# Editor on TabbedPage on Lenovo tablet does not show all text

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a simple test app using `Xamarin.Forms v. 2.3.4.247` (but the problem is on the newest version of `Xamarin.Forms` as well) as shown below. 
But when I fill the `Editor` with multiple lines like

```
This
is
a
test.
This
is
a
test.
```

On my Lenovo Tablet. If I then tap on the 1st visible line, Only the 1st line is visible, and I cannot scroll down to see more of the Editor.

An example is shown on this picture
[image: Example of the Editor, when text is focused]

[image: Example of the Editor without focus]

The code for the test app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
      x:Class="TestApp.MainPage">

   <ContentPage Title="Test">
      <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Label Text="Title" Grid.Row="0" />
         <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,10" Orientation="Vertical">
               <Label Text="Test" />
               <Button Text="Choose a project" />
               <Label Text="Project description" />
               <Label Text="Date" />
               <DatePicker />
               <Label Text="Employee" />
               <Picker>
                  <Picker.Items>
                     Test
                  </Picker.Items>
               </Picker>
               <Label Text="Payment-type" />
               <Picker />
               <Label Text="Amount" />
               <Entry />
               <Entry />
               <Label Text="Description" />
               <Editor MinimumHeightRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
               <Button />
            </StackLayout>
         </ScrollView>
      </Grid>
   </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

I have only attached the xaml-code, as the C# code only have `InitializeComponent`

How can I make it possible for the user to scroll in all the text?

Answer (score 0):

> If I then tap on the 1st visible line, Only the 1st line is visible, and I cannot scroll down to see more of the Editor.

**You put your `Editor` in `ScrollView`**, that's why you can't scroll the `Editor`. In your situation, when you try scroll the `Editor`, it will generate an touch event in system, but both `Editor` and `ScrollView` want get this event so that they could scroll. And finally we could see from the effect, the `ScrollView` intercept this touch events so your `Editor` can't receive this touch event. As a result, `ScrollView` could scroll but your `Editor` can't.

You could use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to handle with this event conflict in native platform. For example, in `Android`, you could use [RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)) to tell `ScrollView` do not intercept this touch events :

> Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).
>
> This parent should pass this call onto its parents. This parent must obey this request for the duration of the touch (that is, only clear the flag after this parent has received an up or a cancel.

Here is my code and it works fine on my side :

Change your `Editor` to :

```
<local:MyEditor MinimumHeightRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" />
```

`MyEditor` :

```
public class MyEditor : Editor
{
}
```

`MyEditorRenderer` for `Android` :

```
public class MyEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                //Parent.Parent.Parent ==> ScrollViewRenderer
                Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                //need to handle this touch event
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                //Parent.Parent.Parent ==> ScrollViewRenderer
                Parent.Parent.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do it :( 
I am still stucked with scrolling the `Editor` using the cursor :(

Comment: @Lasse Madsen, I have update my answer, could you please check whether this  effect is you want? If I misunderstand you, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: The problem is, that it is working on some devices but not Lenovo Tablet :( On my Samsung Galaxy S7 it worked without any modification